# Remove link for linked table in access

Tags: ms-access

Had created a linked table in MS ACCESS 97. Need to remove the link and make the table static so that, even if the data in backend db is removed or altered, this should not affect the table data in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "make table" sql query in order to get the data into a local table then you can delete your linked table, SQL something like:

```
SELECT * INTO LocalTable FROM LinkedTable
```